# what does the give_me_a_name mean?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I have write the code below in the clion:

```
Student student[] = {
            Student("Larry", 95.5, "This is Larry", 1);
            Student("Paul", 78.0, "This is Paul", 2);
            Student("Tom", 80.0, "This is Tom", 3);

    };
```

and it hints a clang-tidy: `object destroyed immediately after the creation; did you mean to name the object?` If I follow it, the code is changed to:

```
Student student[] = {
            Student("Larry", 95.5, "This is Larry", 1);
            Student give_me_a_name("Paul", 78.0, "This is Paul", 2);
            Student("Tom", 80.0, "This is Tom", 3);

    };
```

So what does the `give_me_a_name` mean? And why there could be such syntax?

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but when declaring an array of objects you'll want to separate the object-declarations by commas, not by semicolons.

Comment: You're separating elements of your array with `;` instead that `,`, this doesn't look like valid C++ code.

Comment: I find this problem and fix it, however the give_me_a_name still confuses me...

Comment: `give_me_a_name`  there is a syntax error. Also, the semicolons there are syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly what it sounds like. You used semicolons instead of commas, which made Clang think that you're constructing an object and immediately discarding it as if you had `Student("Paul", 78.0, "This is Paul", 2);` by itself. Therefore it suggests you to store the constructed object in an variable by giving it a name. Clang doesn't know what name you would want, so it puts a placeholder name there for you to replace.